# After adding large png images .SO created leading to increase in app size

Tags: android, apk, lib

I replaced some png images in my project and the app bundle did not build successfully as the png files were too large each 2-3mb. I then changed the images with some jpegs which were a few hundred kb in size per file. After that when I built the app the size of the app went from 9mb to 27 mb. I analyzed the apk and most of the size is due to some lib files

[image: apk analysis]

I deleted the build folder to remove any old files but it did not help.I excluded all .so files but the apk is not installing without them. I tried making a bundle but that is also the same size.
What should I do to revert back to the old apk size.

Comment: Instead of using jpeg convert your png images to WebP

Comment: the combined size of the jpeg files is a 500kb which is not an issue. Do you know how the .so files get created and how to safely remove them??

Comment: show your gradle file

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi" // includes ARM SO files only, so no x86 SO file

            }
        }
    }

Comment: apk size is still large with armfiles around 15mb

Comment: which .so file you used ?

Comment: I do not what they are , I am noticing them after I analyzed my apk

Comment: post your app level gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [**`Add multi-density vector graphics`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio)

> Android Studio includes a tool called Vector Asset Studio that helps
>   you add material icons and import Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG) and
>   Adobe Photoshop Document (PSD) files into your project as vector
>   drawable resources. Using vector drawables instead of bitmaps reduces
>   the size of your APK because the same file can be resized for
>   different screen densities without loss of image quality.

You should use SVG images instead of JPG/PNG.

To make your app as small as possible, you should enable shrinking in your release build to remove unused code and resources. When enabling shrinking, you also benefit from obfuscation, which shortens the names of your app’s classes and members, and optimization, which applies more aggressive strategies to further reduce the size of your app.

Read [**`Shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

```
  android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
            // your project's release build type.
            minifyEnabled true

            // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
            // Android Gradle plugin.
            shrinkResources true

            // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
            // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
            // R8 configuration files.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: yes I use svg in my projects but these were image files that I had to use. They are just around 500kb in total, I cannot understand where the .so files came from

Comment: thanks it worked minify and shrink resources did the trick... the .so files completely disappeared. Could you tell me how they were created in the first place so that I can avoid such issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think images are not the issues from the dex files you have created I think you have included big libraries or many libraries?

Comment: no I have a youtube.jar file for the youtube player. The app was 9mb in size this just happened for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `minifyEnabled true` to shrink resources  in gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NDK abiFilters` in your app module’s `build.gradle` like this:

```
android {
 defaultConfig {
        //...
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi"
        }
    }
}
```

You can also exclude the specific *.so files that you don't want:

```
packagingOptions {
  exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/lib.so'
  exclude 'lib/mips/lib.so'
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that. The apk is being built but its not installing, I do not even know how these files got created in the first place

Comment: @PembaTamang, what happens when you exculde all the .so files with `exclude "lib/armeabi-v7a/**"`?

Comment: The apk is built but cannot be installed

Comment: @PembaTamang: Okay can you add, if you didn't already, `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` to your `gradle.properties` file & then a clean build. Let me know if it gets installed?